# Write the same xml elements from different files only once in output file with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several xml files that all have certain elements in common and some elemtens exclusive to them. I need to output the value of those elements only once to another xml-document using xslt. What's the best way to do that?

Example:

file a.xml

```
<someelement>Value</someelement>
<aelement>value</aelement>
```

file b.xml

```
<someelement>Value</someelement>
<belement>value</belement>
```

file c.xml

```
<someelement>Value</someelement>
<celement>value</celement>
```

Output.xml

```
<someelement>Value</someelement>
<aelement>value</aelement>
<belement>value</belement>
<celement>value</celement>
```

I iterate over a file containing all the paths of the xml files in the folders and subfolders and I access the elements with the doc function.

However, at the moment, the common elements appear several times in the output document.

Is that possible with xslt 2.0, using Saxon9he?

Thanks for help and tips!

Comment: None of those examples are XML, they all have more than one root-level element.

Comment: Can you also show the XSLT you currently have? Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to identify duplicates, based on the element name, the element name and content?

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose your "index" file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<index>
    <file name="a.xml"/>
    <file name="b.xml"/>
    <file name="c.xml"/>
</index>
```

and a "content" file, for example a.xml, is like this (like you wrote in the question, but with a wrapper element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<awrapper>
    <someelement>Value</someelement>
    <aelement>a value</aelement>
    <aelement>a value bis</aelement>
</awrapper>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <mergeresult>
            <!-- start processing the first file -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="index/file[1]">
                <xsl:with-param name="usedNames" select="()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </mergeresult>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <xsl:param name="usedNames" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="tree" select="document(@name)"/>
        <xsl:message select="(@name, $usedNames)"/>
        <!-- add only the xml elements with "new" names -->
        <xsl:sequence select="$tree/*/*[not((local-name()) = $usedNames)]"/>
        <!-- continue processing the next file -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::file[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="usedNames" select="
                distinct-values(($usedNames, for $el in $tree/*/* return local-name($el)))"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mergeresult>
   <someelement>Value</someelement>
   <aelement>a value</aelement>
   <aelement>a value bis</aelement>
   <belement>b value</belement>
   <celement>c value</celement>
</mergeresult>
```

The proposed stylesheet:

- identify duplicates based on element name only (not sure if this is what you need)
- is independent from the name of the document element of the "content" files (`awrapper` in my example, could be different for each content file)
- works well even if a "content" file contains several elements with the same name (= it puts them all in the output, in my example both `aelement` are preserved)
- needs to be adapted to the actual element / attribute names of your "index" file (in my example, `index`, `file` and `@name`)